# Set up Sub Domain

Tags: subdomain

I bought my domain name from 123-reg and can control the DNS, Name server, forwarding etc there, I have now purchased my hosting from webfaction.

I see in 123-reg there is a section to create a sub domain but after creation this just gives me the option for a forward.

My question is do I set up my subdomains on 123-reg or in Webfaction?

Comment: Sorry but this isn't a question but rather a request for a step-by-step tutorial which would soon get outdated whenever 123reg or Webfaction do a GUI update to their website. As a customer of 123 reg and Webfaction, between them, they should be able to provide you with the information you need, either on their website, by phone or email.

Comment: No actually Steve seems to have explained it to me.

Comment: @Simon, actually the steps are generic.  If I gave specific cPanel or plesk instructions your point would be valid.

Comment: @Steve The question was specific to "123-reg and Webfaction", we already have a vast amount of generic questions and answers in relation to how to setup DNS records on Pro Webmasters, so while helpful, your answer, is no different to other answers on the site found in similar questions, so the closure reason was not invalid, however I could have, pointed the user in the right direction but I was pushed for time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since DNS is at 123-reg, you need to set it up in both places.

Step 1 add the subdomain at 123-reg.  This adds it to DNS.  But by default it will be pointing to the 123-reg server most likely so...

Step 2 is to edit DNS pointing the A record to the IP address of webfaction instead of 123-reg.  Now the internet knows where to find the website of your subdomain.

Step 3: so that a visitor arriving at webfaction ends up at the right place, you need to add the subdomain there.

Step 4: wait some time for DNS to propagate and then do a happy dance.

Comment: However i have changed the name server to webfaction? I will have a play thankfully this will be a test site whilst i get it all set up. My idea is as theres a few elements and applications to use subdomains instead of sub directories

Comment: then you do it all at webfaction.